# Where's the critical hit location on Rathyds?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Where's the critical hit location on Rathyds?

I've killed over 700, maybe over 1000, and only seen them report crits, like, thrice at most?

Where do I aim for crits, and do only natural ones, a.k.a non-Shuggurath-born ones have critical hit points?