# What enemies are without critical hit locations?

Tags: borderlands-series

Inspired by my question about [Rathyds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/368876/wheres-the-critical-hit-location-on-rathyds), which *might* not have a critical hit location...

*Are* there enemies without a critical hit location? If so, what are they?